# Scrolling a 3D Object and it's Texture Upwards

Tags: c#, windows, xna

So I'm building a windows game, and I've got some text as a texture on a primitive.  I'm trying to scroll the primitive upwards, but cannot accomplish this.  I've tried simply adding a value to the Y position of the Vector3, but there's issues here.

I initialize the vertexes with:

```
verts = new VertexPositionTexture[4];
verts[0] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(-xPosition, yPosition, 0), new        Vector2(0,0));
verts[1] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(xPosition, yPosition, 0), new Vector2(1, 0));
verts[2] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(-xPosition, negY, 0), new Vector2(0, 1));
verts[3] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(xPosition, negY, 0), new Vector2(1, 1));
```

Then When I try to get this to scroll upwards by adding to the Y coordinates, several things can happen.

If I add to both the variables for the y coordinates like this :

```
yPosition += .01f;
negY += .01f;

verts[0].Position.Y = yPosition;
verts[1].Position.Y = yPosition;
verts[2].Position.Y = negY;
verts[3].Position.Y = negY;
```

The texture, or the primitive all together doesn't even show up anymore.  If I comment out the negY += .01f, the top of the primitive scrolls upwards, but this begins to distort the texture obviously.  Why doesn't this work?!  Why does adding to the negY bork the whole deal?

Comment: Have you tried a pure white texture to see, where the primitive really is? Are you sure that `negY` is not touched by another code snippet? Altering the vertex buffer is no good idea at all. Instead you should use the world transform of your effect (with a translation).